# How can get ports or enviroment variable from docker-compose.yml

Tags: node.js, docker-compose

I had try `process.env.port` to get port variable in environment but it has nothing to change when I build docker. And how can get port from mongo if I have two services docker like that

```
services:
  app:
    image: lostproperty
    container_name: lost-property
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:3100:3000"
    environment:
      - port :"3100"
      - API_URL:"http://localhost:3000/lost-property/"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes: 
      -  ../app:/var/www/html
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - "127.0.0.1:27018:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    environment: 
      - MONGO_URL:"mongodb://localhost:27017/lost-property"`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure that both containers are able to talk to eachother using their container names by including this in your docker-compose file.  This way lost-property can talk to mongo with mongodb://mongo:27017

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: my-network
```

You probably want to create a .env file in the same directory as the docker-compose.yml  In the .env use something like

```
MONGO_PORT=27017
MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo:27017/lost-property
API_URL=http://localhost:3000/lost-property/
PORT=3100
```

In you docker-compose file use the environment config like so

```
services:
  app:
    environment:

    image: lostproperty
    container_name: lost-property
    ports:
      - ${PORT}:${PORT}
    environment:
      - PORT
      - API_URL
      - MONGO_PORT
      - MONGO_URL
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    volumes: 
      -  ../app:/var/www/html
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    restart: always
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - ${MONGO_PORT}:${MONGO_PORT}
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db
    environment: 
      - MONGO_URL
```

use VALUE for environment parts and ${VALUE} anywhere else, like in ports.
Then in your app.js or index.js or whatever you can get the ports and urls with

```
process.env.MONGO_PORT
process.env.MONGO_URL
process.env.PORT
process.env.API_URL
```

You can type

```
docker-compose config
```

To see what the config looks like before running docker-compose up

Also if you are running an api server with something like express you will need to use 0.0.0.0 as the ip to listen on, not 127.0.0.1 if you want to be able to access/test it from outside of the containers and their network

Answer (score 0):

First of all, dockerfile has a `EXPOSE` sentence, where you expose a specific port for your container. You cannot change that exposure.

Second, San Fransisco Sunrise said, you can use same network and link it.